# Create N folders with Script

Tags: shell

I want to create a script that:  Execute command to create N folders with the name "exN", where N goes from 0 to N (N must have two digits) (ex: ex01 ex02 ex03 ex03 ex04 ex05);

In directory: `/home/teste/folha1/it/scripts/`

I think it's just better to do a script with cicle while?

I'm new at shell script, i don't understand well

But i just have this initial code:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: *cicle*? Do you mean a *loop*?

Answer (score 0):

Bash one liner for creating the relevant dirs

```
mkdir ex{01..05}
```

To make it dynamic, here's a script that takes in *N* as input to generate required number of directories

```
#!/bin/bash

N=$1

# assuming dir some/path exists
bash -c "mkdir some/path/ex{01..$N}"
```

Comment: but i have a cicle "infiinite" 0 to N

Comment: what do you mean by 'join all'?

Comment: i have to create a cicle, and then i input a number and the script create so many folders i want

Comment: so, your script needs to take an input which will determine how many directories to create?

Comment: nice, thanks, but, how to join this with a location to this create folders? in this case in : /home/teste/folha1/it/scripts/

Comment: just add the directory name as prefix ' bash -c "mkdir some/path/ex{01..$N}" '

Comment: so in this case: 
bash -c "mkdir /home/teste/folha1/it/scripts//ex{01..$N}"